# Understand Kinect Facetracker.track() method

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm Using Kinect v1 with SDK 1.8. I need to pass my data to `faceTracker.Track()` method.

But in constructor of `track()` is asking Skeleton parameter at the end.
But cannot take directly skeleton data to skeleton object. It provides as an data array.

How can I pass data to this `faceTracker.Track()` method as the track method requested?

The following is the way I tried.

```
using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = allFramesReadyEventArgs.OpenSkeletonFrame())
{
    if (skeletonFrame != null && this.skeletonData != null) // check that a frame is available
    {
        skeletonData = new Skeleton [newSensor.SkeletonStream.FrameSkeletonArrayLength];
        skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(this.skeletonData); // get the skeletal information in this frame
        this.skeletonData = new Skeleton[this.newSensor.SkeletonStream.FrameSkeletonArrayLength];    
    }
}
```

track method

```
 if (faceTracker == null)
 {
     try
     {
         faceTracker = new FaceTracker(sensorChooser.Kinect);
     }
     catch (InvalidOperationException)
     {
         //write something
     }

     if (faceTracker != null)
     {
         FaceTrackFrame frame = faceTracker.Track(
            sensorChooser.Kinect.ColorStream.Format,
            colorImageData, 
            sensorChooser.Kinect.DepthStream.Format, 
            colorPixels, 
            skeletonData);
      }
  }
```

i defined `Skeleton [] skeletonData ;`as this

and follwing is the track method given in Kinect SDK

```
 public FaceTrackFrame Track(
            ColorImageFormat colorImageFormat, 
            byte[] colorImage, 
            DepthImageFormat depthImageFormat, 
            short[] depthImage, 
            Skeleton skeletonOfInterest)
        {
            return this.Track(colorImageFormat, colorImage, depthImageFormat, depthImage, skeletonOfInterest, Rect.Empty);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Skeleton skeleton in this.skeletonData)
                {
                    if (skeleton.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked
                        || skeleton.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.PositionOnly)
                    {
                        // We want keep a record of any skeleton, tracked or untracked.
                        if (!this.trackedSkeletons.ContainsKey(skeleton.TrackingId))
                        {
                            this.trackedSkeletons.Add(skeleton.TrackingId, new SkeletonFaceTracker());
                        }

                        // Give each tracker the upated frame.
                        SkeletonFaceTracker skeletonFaceTracker;
                        if (this.trackedSkeletons.TryGetValue(skeleton.TrackingId, out skeletonFaceTracker))
                        {
                            skeletonFaceTracker.OnFrameReady(this.Kinect, colorImageFormat, colorImage, depthImageFormat, depthImage, skeleton);
                            skeletonFaceTracker.LastTrackedFrame = skeletonFrame.FrameNumber;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I solved it as above with the help of kinect toolkit 1.8 the project FaceTrackingBasics-WPF application.